# When is someone culpable for being tricked

Tags: philosophy-of-law, moral-agency, responsibility

Hypothetical and odd scenario. Person A is tricked into thinking person B is threatening them, and so destroys both their lives. Person A can very easily check if it's real, but refuses to. Person B can do nothing further than they already have.

1. is person A's fate more tragic?
2. is person A culpable for both their fates?

I am not asking about the legality of not checking, though you are welcome to reply and draw from the law. As someone pointed out, we usually think someone is culpable for a false belief when they are to *blame* for it (that's what culpable means, deserving blame).

By analogy, if assistance is very simple and easily offered, then we might blame absolutely anyone who refuses to offer it.

Comment: Typically we blame person A to a degree that depends on how clever the trick is.

Comment: assume it's reasonably *convincing*, but not necessarily without flaws, and can be tested easily @Daron

Comment: You still need to specify a system of morality. There are loads of them.

Comment: Religion has a lot to say about such scenarios. Philosophy did something natural after. The question that follows has the word "right" in it. Bonam Fortunam *homo viator*.

Comment: "*Fool me once, shame on you; fool me twice, shame on me*" is a good rule of thumb. Naivete is not culpable, gullibility is. Refuses to check why? Or, perhaps, just does not think of it. Generally, culpability depends on prior experience, whether there is reasonable expectation of or responsibility to check, as in [duty of care](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duty_of_care), and whether there is reasonable likelihood that the checking would uncover the deceit.

Comment: thanks @Conifold useful comment

Comment: @Conifold can you say more about "checking"? what if they don't want to check for selfish reasons, like regretting their own gullibility etc.? i think that would be a case of hypocrisy anyway

Comment: "Selfish reasons" is a loaded expression that already presupposes the answer. You'll have to add much more specifics to your scenario, neutrally described, for a cogent response. There are few general answers to general questions in ethics, it is not physics, everything turns on context and nuance, circumstances that generality leaves out.

Comment: yeah true. the problem is the scenario is bizarre and psychotic/imagined. so anyway it depends on how convincing and motive only or potentially other factors @Conifold ?

Comment: "Person A can very easily check if it's real" This presumes libertarian free will. I have instead argued in my answer that people are victims of circumstances.

Comment: by extension then no-one is to blame for anything @DennisFrancisBlewett any action or behaviour or absence of action

Comment: That's the general idea I'm spinning.

Comment: ha ok crazy @DennisFrancisBlewett well sure, that makes sense.

Comment: Even if someone were to argue via compatibilism that the matter could have been easily checked, they need to prove that choice exists rather than people being compelled to behave as automatons.

Comment: why not yeah @DennisFrancisBlewett maybe no-one is to blame for anything

Comment: well anyway, i believe this (imaginary) person is now morally culpable for being tricked. i have proven it to a reasonable standard, and the only thing stopping them even believing me, let alone checking, is, i suppose, fear.

Comment: "A was falsely lead to think B threatened them and, although A could have verified but refused to do so, A chose to react by destroying B's life" what strikes me here is not so much the gullibility of A but their callousness: A should be expected to at least assess the situation before making a move to destroy someone's life. At least I would expect someone who wants to destroy MY life to have a solid reason to do so. If you look at it this way it's clear A is at the very list acting in an antisocial manner.

Comment: fwiw @Daron i don't think it was a very clever trick. it needed some ingenuity (to come up with the idea) and skill at hacking, but all things considered neither of these are off the chart, and the trick is quite simple/easily refuted, at least for clever people, so...

Answer (score 2):

> When is someone culpable for being tricked

When the said someone is blameworthy because blameworthiness signifies that the said someone is culpable.

> when are we blameworthy for what we don't know

When blame is reasonably attributed for such.

When the law (the forces of nature) reasonably deems so.

I do not think that the forces of nature ever do such, as people are victims of circumstances rather than instigators of natural events (such seems to be a fact of nature).

Man's law (which involves man's take on morality) is not representative of the law. It is part of "the law" but the part is not representative of the whole.

Comment: ok when are we blameworthy for what we don't know, especially when we are tricked into a false belief

Comment: if you delete your answer (which is more like a comment) then i can delete my question

Comment: My answer was a thesis. I have edited my response. I prefer if you have a new question to make a new post on such. I checked with ChatGPT on the topic and did not care for its responses.

Comment: @prof_post I edited once more. I noticed a failure to use the term "reasonably."

Comment: haha ok thanks sorry about chat gpt

Comment: Edited once more. Have a nice day.

Comment: i proved it was a trick.

Comment: @prof_post Please make responses to answers to your questions on StackExchange as critiques of the answer as much as possible. Not doing so disrupts the ecosystem around here.

Comment: ha i find that really annoying. are my questions that bad?

Comment: oh i see what you mean: we can never be blamed for our epistemic failures (whether or not we can our moral ones). i absolutely disagree, but thanks

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's enough to say that someone is culpable for being tricked when a reasonable person in their position would not be tricked. Perhaps they also need to act in such a way as to damage someone else or perhaps themselves. Without that harm aspect, it is just a fleeting epstemic failure and, though they may lack epistemic virtue, I'd have thought that their virtue in general is not implicated by their being tricked: until it affects their behaviour.

That's one way of looking at inaction as a virtuous response to wideranging illusion and lies.